# Odoo docker, how to create database from command lines?

Tags: docker, odoo

I want to create database from command line with docker. I try these lines

`$ docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo --name db postgres:9.5`

`$ docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo -- -d test`

But I got these errors

```
2017-05-17 05:58:37,441 1 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0-20170207
2017-05-17 05:58:37,442 1 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf
2017-05-17 05:58:37,442 1 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/addons/10.0', u'/mnt/extra-addons', u'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons']
2017-05-17 05:58:37,442 1 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@172.17.0.2:5432
2017-05-17 05:58:37,443 1 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/odoo", line 9, in <module>
    odoo.cli.main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/cli/command.py", line 64, in main
    o.run(args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/cli/server.py", line 164, in run
    main(args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/cli/server.py", line 138, in main
    odoo.service.db._create_empty_database(db_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/service/db.py", line 79, in _create_empty_database
    with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 622, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 164, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 505, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 573, in borrow
    **connection_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "172.17.0.2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

What is the problem, are there other solution to do this?

Comment: Can you provide your `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf`? It attempts to use the default settings for the database connection. However, you will need to specify the mysql container as the database host.

Comment: It seems to work with docker for mac. Could you clean up your environment (remove images and containers)? Or could you check if it is possible to ping the db container within odoo?

Comment: I can confirm that the setup is working. Odoo can connect to the db container

Comment: Thanks problem is solved. I confirm I can connect and do operation on odoo container.
I got this problem because I tried to connect throught Gitlab CI. After I try locally on the runner I could do all task without problem with odoo v8, v9 or v10 container. The problem is on postgres container and Gitlab CI.
I open other question on it if you are interested to investigate more deeper.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040764/gitlab-ci-docker-cant-make-any-operation-on-postgres-container